# .ie9 css selector

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I came across a css selector in the form `.ie9` in a css file:

```
.ie9 .fc-calendar .fc-row > div, .ie9 .fc-calendar .fc-head > div
```

I guessed it's a IE9-specific selector, but I can't find reference about it anywhere. So is it something built-in or just some custom class made for the site?

If it's something built-in, is there an equivalence for IE10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). It adds classes to the `html` tag, so that you can cater your CSS to fit different versions of ie. Also, modernizr tests what features of javascript are available on the browser that has loaded your page and adds these as classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's just a class selector.

```
<div class="ie9">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different stylesheets for IE based on the version in use by placing this in your  area:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-styles.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The above, for instance, will only call the stylesheet if the browser is IE9 or above, hence the "gte" for "Greater Than or Equal to".

It doesn't require javascript and is technically valid HTML, as it is simply a comment block that is interpreted by Internet Explorer.